# WPF Presentation Framework Exception :(

Tags: wpf, exception

So I am working on my final project for a summer course and I get this following exception.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Looking in the call stack, its doing all of its preprocessing, and it occurs. It isnt even starting my application so I dont think it could be my code. Is it possible I deleted some file on accident? My project was running fine. I made a few changes, one was adding a reference to a class I was going to use, but then changed my mind. I removed it, made some changes, and then went to run it, and bam! Yes, version control may of saved me from the issue, rookie mistake!

Any help is appreciated!

edit: there actually appears to be several exceptions, here is part of the output window

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in StockAnalysis.exe A first chance exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   System.Xaml.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

Comment: I tried copying all the code to a new project, and I am still having the problem.

Comment: Try to run it in Visual Studio so the exception dialog comes up and click the **View Details** link and check its `InnerException` property.

Comment: What version of the .Net framework have you got installed on the problem machine, and what version are you targetting?

Comment: I went into the Exception tree for the System exceptions and had it throw any NullReference exceptions so I could break it and show me where in the code it was happening. I was trying to reference a window I had not created yet. Problem solved!

Comment: Alright, I'm going write up my suggestion as the answer and post.

Comment: @obz - you need to add that as an answer, not just a comment, that makes it easier for other people to see what the answer is, and you can also mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `TargetInvocationException` almost always has `InnerException` set to something. Try to run it in Visual Studio so the exception dialog comes up, click the "View Details" link and you'll be able to expand the exception's properties to find out what really happened.

In 100% of the times I've gotten `TargetInvocationException`, its `InnerException` was not null. Most of the time (depending on your exception-handling), there's only the 1 `InnerException`.

*It's a good rule to keep in mind: Always check `InnerException`.*

Comment: You saved my day joel.. :)

Comment: What if the inner Exception is null as well. I ran into this scenario